# Default credentials can not be used to assume new style deployment roles

Tags: aws-cdk

Following [pipelines readme](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html) to set up a deployment pipeline, I ran

```
$ env CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP=1 npx cdk bootstrap \
    --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess \
    aws://[ACCOUNT_ID]/us-west-2
```

to create the necessary roles. I would assume the roles would automatically add sts assume role permissions from my account principle. However, when I run `cdk deploy` I get the following warning

> current credentials could not be used to assume
> 'arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT_ID]:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-[ACCOUNT_ID]-us-west-2',
> but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.

I have root credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Looking at the deploy role policy, I don't see any sts permissions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 19):

You will need to add permission to assume the role to the credentials from which you are trying to execute `cdk deploy`

```
{
  "Sid": "assumerole",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
     "sts:AssumeRole",
     "iam:PassRole"
  ],
  "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-readOnlyRole",
     "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-*",
     "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in CodeBuild, which credentials do I need to add it to. I can't seem to find which credentials CodeBuild uses.

Comment: This is the answer I needed as we assume a role before performing a CDK deploy as we also use the AWS CLI.

Comment: For those not in china, use "arn:aws:iam" instead of "arn:aws-cn:iam"

Comment: I had to modify the trust policy of each of these roles to let my user assume them in order to have it working

Answer (score 10):

1. First thing you need to do is **enabling the verbose mode** to see what is actually happenning.

   ```
   cdk deploy --verbose
   ```

   If you see similar message below. Continue with step 2. Otherwise, you need to address the problem by understanding the error message.

   > Could not assume role in target account using current credentials User: arn:aws:iam::XXX068599XXX:user/cdk-access is not authorized to perform: sts
   > :AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::XXX068599XXX:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-XXX068599XXX-us-east-2 . Please make sure that this role exists i
   > n the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
2. Check **S3 buckets related to CDK** and CloudFormation stacks from AWS Console. **Delete** them manually.
3. **Enable the new style bootstrapping** by one of the method mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping-templates)
4. Bootstrap the stack using below command. Then it should create all required roles automatically.

   ```
   cdk bootstrap --trust=ACCOUNT_ID --cloudformation-execution-policies=arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess --verbose
   ```

**NOTE:** If you are working with docker image assets, make sure you have setup your repository before you deploy. New style bootstrapping does not create the repos automatically for you [as mentioned in this comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8483#issuecomment-644651345).

Comment: This didn't work for me. `cdk --version` 2.53.0 (build 7690f43)

Comment: What is your exact issue trying to resolve? CDK new versions have new style bootstrap anyway.

Answer (score 7):

This may be of use to somebody... The issue could be a mismatch of regions. I spotted it in verbose mode - the roles were created for us-east-1 but I had specified eu-west-2 in the bootstrap. For some reason it had not worked. The solution was to set the region (by adding AWS_REGION=eu-west-2 before the cdk deploy command).

Comment: oof gets me every time. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to run `cdk bootstrap` with those credentials against your account `[ACCOUNT_ID]`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error. The critical part of my error was

```
failed: Error: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/<>/version not found.
```

I had to re-run using the new bootstrap method that creates the SSM parameter. To run the new bootstrap method first set CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP via `export CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP=1`

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: If you're using CDK Pipelines, add the following to your synth `pipelines.CodeBuildStep`:

```py
role_policy_statements = [
    iam.PolicyStatement(
        actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
        resources=["*"],
        conditions={"StringEquals": {"iam:ResourceTag/aws-cdk:bootstrap-role": "lookup"}},
    )
]
```

For example:

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam
from aws_cdk import pipelines

def synth(self, synth_input: pipelines.CodePipelineSource, out_dir: str) -> pipelines.CodeBuildStep:
    return pipelines.CodeBuildStep(
        id="SynthStep",
        input=synth_input,
        commands=[...],
        primary_output_directory=out_dir,
        role_policy_statements=[
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
                resources=["*"],
                conditions={"StringEquals": {"iam:ResourceTag/aws-cdk:bootstrap-role": "lookup"}},
            )
        ],
    )
```

It's also recommended you save and load the `cdk.context.json` file in `commands` somewhere between synth runs to avoid non determinism.

**Resources:**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#context-lookups

*Note*: The official docs show this iam Policy should be specified in the `pipelines.CodePipeline`. There is no `role_policy_statements` in the `pipelines.CodePipeline` construct. You need to add it to the `pipelines.CodeBuildStep`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I was using expired credentials. I was trying to use temporary credentials from AWS SSO, which were expired. The problem was that the error message is misleading: it says

```
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/cdk-xxx999xxx-deploy-role-123456789012-us-east-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
(To get rid of this warning, please upgrade to bootstrap version >= 8)
```

However, applying the `--verbose` flag as suggested above showed the real problem:

```
Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/cdk-xxx999xxx-deploy-role-123456789012-us-east-1'.
Assuming role failed: The security token included in the request is expired
Could not assume role in target account using current credentials The security token included in the request is expired . Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
```

Getting the latest SSO credentials fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After deploying with `--verbose` I could see it was a clock issue in my case:

```
Assuming role failed: Signature expired: 20220428T191847Z is now earlier than 20220428T192528Z (20220428T194028Z - 15 min.)
```

I resolve the clock issue on ubuntu using:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

which then resolves the cdk issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `assumeRole` on cdk resources, here is what fixed my assumerole and the s3 bucket warning during deployment:

```
    {
        "Sid": "assumerolecdk",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
           "sts:AssumeRole",
           "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-readOnlyRole",
           "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-*",
           "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-*",
           "arn:aws:iam::***:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-***-us-east-1"
        ]
      }
```

Make sure you are configured for the correct region.