# Permission to AssumeRole for useraccount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I set up some resources by cdk.

After first setup finished, some permisions around role will be removed.

Now I bumped into this error when updating.

```
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::3144113XXXXX:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-3144113XXXXX-ap-northeast-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
```

I think this means that user accounts needs to assume `cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-3144113XXXXX-ap-northeast-1`?

And this is related with `sts:AssumeRole`?

However I could not find the iems in polycies including `sts:AssumeRole`.

What policy should I add?

Comment: You will need to add permission to assume the role to the credentials from which you are trying to execute cdk deploy as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68898448/12326605)